# get facebook user access token via python

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api-v2.0, robobrowser

i actually want to grab the facebook user access token via python programmatically.
i use the following code:

```
import re
from robobrowser import RoboBrowser
browser = RoboBrowser(history=True)
browser.open('http://www.facebook.com/')
form = browser.get_form(id='login_form')
browser.form['email'] = 'My email'
form['pass'].value ='my password'
browser.submit_form(form)
```

and i log in with success. how can i grab the **user access token**?

Comment: Did you solve it?